# In postman, how can i run a new test based on whether another test has passed or failed?

Tags: javascript, json, postman, postman-testcase

I have two tests test A and test B. I want B to run only if A has passed. How can i do that in postman?

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function() {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
pm.test("Check if fruits found with this search criteria", function() {
    pm.expect(responseData.Message).to.not.eql("No fruits found with this search criteria");
});
```

I want to run a third test only if these two test cases pass. How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply nest your tests:

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function() {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);

    pm.test("Check if fruits found with this search criteria", function() {
        pm.expect(responseData.Message).to.not.eql("No fruits found with this search criteria");

        pm.test("Third test", function() {
            //pm.expect()...
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What about when i want to run a third test case if only first two test cases fail?

Comment: You mean, if `test1 AND test2` fail, you want to run `test3`?

Comment: Please have a look here: https://gist.github.com/christianbaumann/59a80f0bf11221b49226e5b149a28e8d